# Using SOAP to connect to a web service, please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to connect to a web service using PHP/SOAP and for some reason I can't.
I think there might be a problem in these lines:

```
$client = new soapclient('http://212.199.64.197/LeadCollector/LeadCollector.asmx');
$client->debug_flag=true;
$err = $soapclient->getError(); 
$return = $client->call('InsertCollaboratorMoreLeadDetails', $webservice);
```

This is the error code I am getting:

: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://212.199.64.197/LeadCollector/LeadCollector.asmx' : Premature end of data in tag html line 3 in /home/uboopco1/public_html/llcproject.org/wp-content/plugins/fire-form/test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /home/uboopco1/public_html/llcproject.org/wp-content/plugins/fire-form/test.php(8): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://212.199....') #1 {main} thrown in

Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `$err` actually say?

Comment: "There might be a problem", "Do you see any problem". Well; no, I don't see anything; but maybe if you post the error your code gives (or any output), we might be able to help you :).

Comment: I may be being firewalled, but I cannot get any response whatsoever from `http://212.199.64.197/LeadCollector/LeadCollector.asmx` with any client, can't even `telnet 212.199.64.197 80` - are you sure the remote service is running...?

Comment: This is the error code, 
Hope it helps, Thanks:

: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://212.199.64.197/LeadCollector/LeadCollector.asmx' : Premature end of data in tag html line 3 in /home/uboopco1/public_html/llcproject.org/wp-content/plugins/fire-form/test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /home/uboopco1/public_html/llcproject.org/wp-content/plugins/fire-form/test.php(8): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://212.199....') #1 {main} thrown in

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you need to add `?wsdl` at the end of the URL.

Like this :

```
$client = new soapclient('http://212.199.64.197/LeadCollector/LeadCollector.asmx?wsdl');
```